# Convergence series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble with this statement:

"If $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges, and $a_n>0$ for all $n$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$$ also converges"

I need to find either a proof or a counterexample. If somebody could give an idea, or a hint, it would be great.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ converges, then this means, there is some $N$ such that $\forall n > N, a_n < 1$. Then, since $0 < a_n^2 < a_n, \forall n > N$, we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n^2 + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_n^2 \le C + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_n,$$
where $C<\infty$ is a constant, and $C = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n^2$. So, we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ converges.

Comment: Thank you so much! I´ll accept the answer as soon as they allow me to do so.

Comment: I think a better exercise for you to think now is, what can you say about $a_n^i$ for $i > 0$?

Comment: Well, I can apply the same principle, right? They all converge, even $a_n^n$

Comment: No problem. But, they don't quite all converge. The bigger $i$ is the faster they converge. (Assuming convergence of the original.) But, what happens when $i$ gets small? Consider the example $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: I was thinking of $i$ as an integer, but if it is in the interval [0,1], then not always, I guess. I could look for a counterexample, maybe $\frac 1 {n^2}$, $i=1/2$

Comment: Thanks :) We thought of the same counterexample, it seems. Thanks for the help, really.

Comment: Excellent! That was the goal. Usually $i> 0$ would imply $i \in \mathbb{R}$, unless otherwise stated.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: We know that $$\lim a_n=0.$$ Moreover, $$\lim\frac{{a_n}^2}{a_n}=\lim a_n=0$$ too. Therefore, the results follows by Limit Comperison Test.

Note that: If $a_n \ge 0$, then the mlg4080's answer fits but this does not, directly.

Comment: this is not limit conparison test,for that test $lim(u_n/v_n)=l\neq 0$.